# Eliminate leading space form field Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, forms, field-codes

I am using Word 2007 and have a form with "Filling in forms" protection. I have a formula field: `{ =Round(Price/0.5, 2) \# "$#,##0.00" }` that shows like this: $ 100.00. The problem is how do I eliminate the space between the $ and the number? It should show like this: $100.00

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "0,00" to "0.00"?

Comment: "$,0.00" would normally be enough to format a dollar amount how you want, assuming your decimal point character is "." And your thousands separator is ",". However, form field number formats can behave a bit differently from the ones in ordinary numeric fields, which is why I haven't posted this as an Answer

Comment: @Adam Oops the "0,00" was a typo. Corrected the question. And yes I often do use the comma as a decimal separator depending on the destination for the document.

Comment: @bibadia The format suggested by Word is "#,##0.00"

Comment: @D_Bester: the format suggested when you select the format in a form field is as you say, and in fact it makes little difference in that case because leading # characters do not introduce extra space, but in other field types such as { = } fields, they do introduce extra space if the number has fewer characters than the pattern. So what I said was correct for { = }. With a FORMTEXT field you have to have at least one # at the beginning. Otherwise, the comma is treated as a literal rather than a thousands separator.

Comment: @D_Bester: re. "use the comma as a decimal separator depnding on the destination for the document", do you mean that you always format numbers with decimal point ".", but sometimes use thousands separators (34,567.89) and sometimes do not (34567.89 )? or do you mean that you somethimes have to format for locales where other characters are used (34.567,89) ? If it's the former, you need a maximum of 1 ",", and you leave "," out altogether if you don't want a thousands separator. If it's the latter, you have to modify the pattern to match the characters used in the locale you are targetting.

Comment: @bibadia I do sometimes have to format for other locales e.g. (34.567,89) but that causes me no problems (other than typos on SO:). It was just a typo in the question, nothing more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually today when I tried again by recreating the field I didn't get the space. So I experimented with it a bit. I clicked on the number in the document and manually inserted a space between the $ and the number. Now I've got the space again and I can't fix it by changing the formula or the number format. So now I've just recreated the problem.

To remove the space I just click on the field in the document and manually delete the space. Done!

I guess I'm more familiar with how things work in Excel and this is very different.

Comment: Never thought to remove the space from the field result as it _should_ be recreated from scratch every time the field is updated. Microsoft Word can be funny sometimes.